# Qml Error: Cannot assign QObject* to QQuickItem

Tags: qt, qml, qqmlcomponent

I have a Rectangle with a MouseArea in ApplicationWindow. By clicking the mousearea, the size of the rectangle should be increased, which works perfectly. But somehow centering the rectangle in the middle of the ApplicationWindow does not work

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

ApplicationWindow {
    id: originalWindow
    visible: true
    width: 1920
    height: 1080
    title: qsTr("Bookshop Management System")


        Rectangle {
            id: searchUserButton
            x: 450
            y: 206

            radius: 10
            width: 200
            height: 200
            color: "#ccc8c8"

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {searchUserButton.width = 1100
                    searchUserButton.height = 600
                    searchUserButton.anchors.centerIn = originalWindow
                    rectangle2.visible = false
                    rectangle3.visible = false
                    rectangle4.visible = false
                    rectangle5.visible = false
                    rectangle6.visible = false
                }

            }

        }
```

The error code is `Error:

```
Cannot assign QObject* to QQuickItem*
```

Comment: try with: `searchUserButton.anchors.centerIn = originalWindow.contentItem`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already set a width and a height of the searchUserButton, so you only have to correctly set x and y coordinates for this button.

```
searchUserButton.x = (originalWindow.width - searchUserButton.width) / 2
searchUserButton.y = (originalWindow.height - searchUserButton.height) / 2
```